# Synced Document Library deleting files on user login to computer

Tags: document-library, onedrive-for-business

We are using SharePoint online and one of the team sites that we have set up is having an issue with its document library. We’ve had documents being deleted from the library when 2 users have logged into their computers. This hasn’t been one or two files that have been deleted but a little over 600 files and has been happening over the last 5 days.

We know that it is happening when they login because the deleted time that is shown in the library’s recycle bin and audit logs matches the time that they logged into their machines in the morning. I also confirmed this this morning when the one user that it seems to be happening consistently for I checked the library and it was fine. They logged in and I refreshed the browser and the files were removed and that user’s name is associated with the deletes in the recycle bin.

I’ve checked the user recycle bin on their machine but none of the files removed from the synced library show up in it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got roaming profiles enabled?

We were having similar problems as the SharePoint folder was replicated to the server as part of the profile data. Excluding SharePoint from the roaming profile solved (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814592) these issues. The issue happening only at login time seems to support this.